# Search box and button don't display in the same line

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce search box on my page and I want the button and the search box itself to display in the same line. I tried using the attribute `inline-block` but it didn't seem to work. 
Source code:

```
<div data-id="b273043" class="elementor-element elementor-element-b273043 searchbar elementor-widget elementor-widget-wp-widget-woocommerce_product_search" data-element_type="wp-widget-woocommerce_product_search.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
            <form role="search" method="get" class="woocommerce-product-search" action="https://www.naotech.com/he/">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="woocommerce-product-search-field-0">חיפוש עבור:</label>
    <input type="search" id="woocommerce-product-search-field-0" class="search-field" placeholder="Search Products" value="" name="s" />
    <button type="submit" value="search">search</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
</form>
```

I tried adding the following CSS and it didn't work

```
form.woocommerce-product-search {
    display: inline-block ;
}
```

[Here](https://www.naotech.com/he/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/)'s a link to the page itself.

Comment: Just try to add `[id^="woocommerce-product-search-field"] {width: auto !important}` somewhere in the end of last added css file.

Comment: Thanks! worked wonderfully.

Comment: look below. I have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to add

```
[id^="woocommerce-product-search-field"] {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

somewhere in the end of last added css file

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the `!important` rule to this style or styling the `input` and `button`. Note that the `!important` rule should only be used as a last resort as it can't be overridden. Instead you should override styles using ordering of your styles (in this case make sure your custom CSS is included after the WooCommerce CSS) and by using specificity. This is how you would style the `input` and `button`:

```
form.woocommerce-product-search input,
form.woocommerce-product-search button
{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

Comment: It often works to prepend `body ` or some other parent element to the selector as well. The `!important` modifier gives me hives.

Comment: Me too! And yes, good suggestion, prepending `body` would make the selector more specific and give it higher priority : )

Answer (score 2):

Please use below code to implement inline form for all browsers.

```
<style>
.form-inline{
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>

<form class="form-inline">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The search input box inside form has width: 100%. Change the width to 50%.